# Python: Finding multiple linear trend lines in a scatter plot

Tags: python, linear-regression

I have the following pandas dataframe -

```
    Atomic Number      R         C
0             2.0   49.0  0.040306
1             3.0  205.0  0.209556
2             4.0  140.0  0.107296
3             5.0  117.0  0.124688
4             6.0   92.0  0.100020
5             7.0   75.0  0.068493
6             8.0   66.0  0.082244
7             9.0   57.0  0.071332
8            10.0   51.0  0.045725
9            11.0  223.0  0.217770
10           12.0  172.0  0.130719
11           13.0  182.0  0.179953
12           14.0  148.0  0.147929
13           15.0  123.0  0.102669
14           16.0  110.0  0.120729
15           17.0   98.0  0.106872
16           18.0   88.0  0.061996
17           19.0  277.0  0.260485
18           20.0  223.0  0.164312
19           33.0  133.0  0.111359
20           36.0  103.0  0.069348
21           37.0  298.0  0.270709
22           38.0  245.0  0.177368
23           54.0  124.0  0.079491
```

The trend between r and C is generally a linear one. What I would like to do if possible is find an exhaustive list of all the possible combinations of 3 or more points and what their trends are with scipy.stats.linregress so that I can find groups of points that fit linearly the best.

[Which would ideally look something like this for the data,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lyc4.png) [(Source)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7cd8/0579214bd512f91c9a89e5fb78c4c9e72556.pdf) but I am looking for all the other possible trends too.

So the question, how do I feed all the  16776915 possible combinations (sum_(i=3)^24 binomial(24, i)) of 3 or more points into lingress and is it even doable without a ton of code?

Comment: Sounds like cherrypicking the data. You normally do not pick datapoints for "best fit", your fit dhould be sble to explain the data.

Comment: So, what did you try? Did it work?

Comment: @EPo Looking at the data qualitatively, I already know the trends that would explain it as the linked paper shows, I want to find more trends than that are readily apparent with some basic knowledge of the periodic table

Comment: @seed I am trying to figure out a loop that would iterate through all of it but this is my first time doing something like this so a bit stuck

Comment: Perhsps you should word your task differently, your description in question and pucture attached are quite different. On the picture you have groups of point that vary by some characteristics, withthe group the trendline is different. Your description is basically "I want to choose from the two columns", which is not too meaningful. Either you want to do clustering (fi ding the groups) or there is already a grouping available (so ething that you say you kniw from periofic table).

Comment: Sorry about typos

Comment: ?Your question lacks clarity of what you are trying to achieve. are you looking for correlation? Why only maximum R values? If know data better than anyone else.

Comment: @EPo Tried to clarify it a bit more in the wording.

Comment: @mad_ I am trying to see if I can find other trends that fit as well as the ones in the published paper I linked above

Comment: I wonder how will you find different trends in the same set of series.

Comment: @mad The linked image might help with understanding that, basically by taking different sets of points together

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My following solution proposal is based on the [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus) algorithm. It is method to fit a mathematical model (e.g. a line) to data with heavy of outliers.

RANSAC is one specific method from the field of [robust regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_regression).

My solution below first fits a line with RANSAC. Then you remove the data points close to this line from your data set (which is the same as keeping the outliers), fit RANSAC again, remove data, etc until only very few points are left.

Such approaches always have parameters which are data dependent (e.g. noise level or proximity of the lines). In the following solution and `MIN_SAMPLES` and `residual_threshold` are parameters which might require some adaption to the structure of your data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model

MIN_SAMPLES = 3

x = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)

xs, ys = [], []

# generate points for thee lines described by a and b,
# we also add some noise:
for a, b in [(1.0, 2), (0.5, 1), (1.2, -1)]:
    xs.extend(x)
    ys.extend(a * x + b + .1 * np.random.randn(len(x)))

xs = np.array(xs)
ys = np.array(ys)
plt.plot(xs, ys, "r.")

colors = "rgbky"
idx = 0

while len(xs) > MIN_SAMPLES:

    # build design matrix for linear regressor
    X = np.ones((len(xs), 2))
    X[:, 1] = xs

    ransac = linear_model.RANSACRegressor(
        residual_threshold=.3, min_samples=MIN_SAMPLES
    )

    res = ransac.fit(X, ys)

    # vector of boolean values, describes which points belong
    # to the fitted line:
    inlier_mask = ransac.inlier_mask_

    # plot point cloud:
    xinlier = xs[inlier_mask]
    yinlier = ys[inlier_mask]

    # circle through colors:
    color = colors[idx % len(colors)]
    idx += 1
    plt.plot(xinlier, yinlier, color + "*")

    # only keep the outliers:
    xs = xs[~inlier_mask]
    ys = ys[~inlier_mask]

plt.show()
```

In the following plot points shown as stars belong to the clusters detected by my code. You also see a few points depicted as circles which are the points remaining after the iterations. The few black stars form a cluster which you could get rid of by increasing `MIN_SAMPLES` and / or `residual_threshold`.

[image]

Comment: +1: RANSAC is the standard approach and seems to be exactly what OP wants---to decide the set of outliers and inliers, and easily implemented for a linear model. I would suggest expanding a bit for OP if they've never seen RANSAC before on what it does and why it's useful for their problem.